# How to implement bootstrap sticky/non-sticky footer?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, footer, sticky-footer

I want implement footer which will stick to the bottom on the non-scroll page and attach to body when page is scrolled.

How do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sample HTML page with Twitter's Bootstrap, Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer, and a full-width footer, fixed for responsive layouts by Aalaap Ghag](https://gist.github.com/aalaap/3066704)